# maven can not import "pinyin4j.jar"

Tags: java, maven, web

want to translate the Chinese to pinyin。So I want to use the rack(pinyin4j.jar).But the maven dependency tree do not contain "pinyin4j".

I have try to use zhe command "mvn clean、mvn compile 、mvn install 、mvn  reimport"

I have try to delete it and add it again.

```
import net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.PinyinHelper;
```

this does not work.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.belerweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>pinyin4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following steps, It is working fine in my system:

1. Go to the location of your project.
   Example: **D:\Project\workspace\com.test.pinyin4j>**
2. Try `mvn clean install`.
3. Update project and it should work fine.

You can check below attached images. It got successfully imported.

[image]

[image]

Note: Don't forget to add pinyin4j dependency in POX file.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.belerweb/pinyin4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.belerweb</groupId>
            <artifactId>pinyin4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```